# stop executing and back to beginning

Tags: php

```
<?php
function a(){ $variable= 'random string'; }


a();


if(file_exists($variable)){
 stop executing and start over again from function a;
}

function b(){ do something }


b();
```

question: how can I stop script and tell it to redo the whole process, go back to function a and run.

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
function a(){ $variable= 'random string'; }
```

You are defining the function `a`. At no point in your snippet is any function called. To call it, you would need:

```
function a(){ $variable= 'random string'; }
a();
```

or

```
a();
function a(){ $variable= 'random string'; }
```

(the point where the function is defined is irrelevant)

In general, the way to "go back to the beginning" would be to use `goto` (this requires PHP 5.3):

```
start:
//do stuff
goto start;
```

If you define no functions or condition the definitions, you can also do:

```
if (!function_exists('a')) {
    function a() {}
}
//do stuff
include __FILE__;
```

However, you should note that any changes of state (e.g. write to globals) will not be rewound by doing any of this. You should also be careful not to cause an infinite loop.

Comment: I smell a php crash coming on :)

Comment: also, you will not be able to redefine your functions.

Comment: yea, just think if he is using a framework, it would not be healthy to run so many checks on classes, functions, constants etc.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Is not threaded so you can't initiate the process again from within the process, there is a hack to do this but you have to close the process and send the outout, then you let the browser restart your process.

```
if(file_exists($variable))
{
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
    exit;
}
```

you can also loop the check to run every 1 second, but this depends on if the above logic is required for every check.

```
$sts = time();
while(!file_exists($variable))
{
    if($sts < timestamp()-10)
    {
        exit;
    }
    sleep(1);
}
```

this would check every second for 10 seconds, otherwise it will exit.

Comment: What is it with people and down voting valid posts today, have i missed something?

Comment: Well, PHP code does not have to be run in a browser. CLI is another possibility for executing PHP code. (I didn't downvote you)

Comment: It wasn't mine, but using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` would be more accurate (would even include the query string).

Comment: yea but 80% run within the browser so it was a valid assumption. and if he wishes to change the the value of the redirect he would ask and ill be happy to help him depending on his situation, with my method the browser will stop executing the redirect function after certain amount of tries, if not he can incorporate session to track the requests.

Answer (score 0):

Is there  a reason you cant just have function a and function b called from a subfunction?

```
function doit()
{
   a();
   b();

   if(file_exists($variable)){
      //stop executing and start over again from function a;
      doit();  //this is the important bit.
   }
   else
   {

   c();
   d();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've described is a classic `while` loop:

```
$keep_going = true;

while($keep_going) {
    function a(){ $variable= 'random string'; }
    function b(){ do something}

    $keep_going = file_exists($variable);
}

function c(){ do something }
function d(){do something }
```

Note that `'random string'` would need to be different each iteration, otherwise you'll get stuck in an infinite loop.

You'll also get stuck in an infinite loop if all possible combinations of `'random string'` are used up, but its likely you'll get serious slow downs in your app long before that, as if a lot of the possible combinations are in use, it could take a large number of iterations before `'random string'` finds a combination that is not in use.

You could avoid some of these problems by using a sequential counter variable instead of a random string.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
while(1)
{
    // ... code ...
    a();

    if (file_exists($variable))
    {
        continue;
    }

    // ... code ...
    b();
}
```

But remember to **break** the loop somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    function a (){
        $variable = "random string";
        return $variable;
    }

    do{
        $variable = a();
    }while (file_exists($variable));

    // do the rest of the process;

    function b(){
        // do something;
    }

    b();
?>
```

First of all `$variable` has no scope on `file_exists($variable)` in your code. you need to return the value or call it global.

then run it through a `do..while` loop.

Hope this clears your problem!